# Determine if external javascripts are loaded correctly

Tags: javascript

I have some external thirdparty `js` files on my page, let say:

```
3rdparty1.js
```

And also I have one of my own:

```
myown1.js
```

I want to perform a condition in `myown.js` that asks if `3rdparty1.js` is successfully loaded or not (e.g. No internet connection, `error 404`, suddenly third party makes `3rdparty1` private, etc.) similar to this code:

```
// inside myown1.js
if(3rdparty1.js_is_loaded_correctly) {

    // performs function found inside 3rdparty1.js
    3rdparty1function();
} else {

    // performs an alternative function (maybe found inside myown.js)
    myownjsbackupfunction();

    // or maybe show prompt messages
    alert("Some functionalities are not available at the moment."
        + " Try reloading this page later.");
}
```

Now, how do you write the proper condition statement for this? Note that `3rdparty1.js` is on a separate domain, if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: You could check if some symbols exported from that library exist. `if (window.something3rdpartyprovided) { ... } `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether `3rdparty1function` has been declared:

```
if (typeof 3rdparty1function !== "undefined") {
    // library OK
```

Comment: Thanks! Your a **lifesaver**.

Comment: A... wait, is `(typeof 3rdparty1function === "function")` valid also?

Comment: @Gideon Yes but the common practice is to test for the definition of the variable. It's best to use it so that other developers recognize your intent.